# how to get a non-const value from a vector

Tags: c++

If I have a class:

```
class T{
  public:
     int Id;
  //some methods, constructor..
}
```

and in other class:

```
vector<T> collection;
```

and want to a write a method:

```
T& getValue(int Id){
   //scanning the vector till i find the right value
 }
```

The problem is that scanning the vector through iterator always give a const value so I get an error about qualifiers. So how do I get a value from a vector? but Not a const one.

EDIT: According to the Answers I tried to so something like this:

```
Group& Server::findGroup(unsigned int userId) const{
    for(auto iterator=groups.begin();iterator!=groups.end();++iterator){
          if(iterator->isInGroup(userId)){
              return (*iterator);
          }
      }
      //throw exception here
}
```

the definition of groups:
vector groups;

This is exactly the same example I gave at first but now T is Group.

Comment: Given you dont want a const I assume you want to modify it within the vector dont you

Comment: What makes you think that scanning the vector through an iterator always gives a const?  If `std::find` is passed non-const iterators, it returns a non-const iterator.

Comment: You can use `std::find` for this purpose (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find))

Comment: @Montaldo yes, I want to modify it within the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should give you a non-`const` iterator and work fine:

```
for(vector<T>::iterator i = collection.begin(); 
    i != collection.end(); ++i) {
    if(Id != i->Id)
        continue;
    // Matching ID! do something with *i here...
    break;
}
```

If this doesn't help, please explain in more detail what is broken.

---

The problem here is the `const` in your declaration:

```
Group& Server::findGroup(unsigned int userId) const //<==THIS
```

That means that `this` is a `const Server*`, and thus everything in it is `const` as well, including `groups`. Which means that `groups.begin()` will return a `const_iterator` instead of an `iterator`.

One thing you *can* do (might not be a good idea; you need to be really sure!) would be to mark `groups` as `mutable`, which lets it be changed even if its enclosing object is `const`:

```
mutable vector<T> groups;
```

Doing this will make `groups.begin()` return a regular `iterator`.

*But* I would instead ask you to reevaluate why this method is declared `const` at all, since you're returning part of the object in a form that *can be changed* and thus you're not really honoring `const`.

Comment: Thanks! but when I write (where you wrote Matching Id) return *i  I get an error about the qualifiers.

Comment: That should work fine. What error do you get? I think something else might be going on.